# Is the API specification for com.firebase.client.Firebase missing?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**I'm searching the API for com.firebase.client.Firebase class, but have failed to find it**. This is the class which provides allows you to access to functions such as `Firebase.setAndroidContext(this)`. Calling functions of this class in code still works, however. To make searching easier, follow [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/packages) to get to the firebase api specifiecation.

Was it replaced?

Comment: What language is this for? I can infer from reading the question, but adding a language tag may draw others in for your benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're working with a very old and deprecated version of the Firebase database client library.  It is no longer supported.

Notice that you're looking for **com.firebase...** but all the new libraries are **com.google.firebase...**.

You should follow the [updated integration instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start).

Comment: Old and deprecated for sure, but the docs are still up here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/ ;-)